# Convert string into DateTime to UTC format in Python, postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

I receive 2 different formats of datetime in string format. But While storing in PostgreSql Database it has to be stored in UTC format.

```
Format 1 : 2017-08-25 01:10:56.910523 -04:00
Format 2 : 2017-08-25 01:10:56.910523 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

Tried using timestamptz in PostgreSql but I guess it doesn't seem to  understand **AMERICA/NEW_YORK** so how can to convert and store in UTC format in DB

-4:00 and AMERICA/NEW_YORK are just example but it can be anything else.

Comment: Did you try the `dateutil.parser`?
Here is a link:
http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html
It should be not to hard to parse the timezone information and reformat it.
Edit: it's actually `from dateutil.tz import gettz`

Comment: for gettz i need to know the timezone right so should I parse the string and get the timezone from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:
First try to parse it altogether, if this fails parse it separately.

```
from dateutil import parser, tz
utc_tz = tz.gettz('UTC')

times = ['2017-08-25 01:10:56.910523 -04:00',
         '2017-08-25 01:10:56.910523 AMERICA/NEW_YORK']

for t in times:
    try:
        utc_time = parser.parse(t).astimezone(utc_tz)
    except ValueError as e:
        _date, _time, _tz = t.split(' ')
        _time_wo_tz = parser.parse(' '.join([_date, _time]))
        _parsed_tz = tz.gettz(_tz.title())
        _time_w_tz = _time_wo_tz.replace(tzinfo=_parsed_tz)
        utc_time = _time_w_tz.astimezone(utc_tz)

    print(utc_time)
```

Comment: `_parsed_tz = tz.gettz(_tz)` is giving None for **AMERICA/NEW_YORK**. Since its none it crashes in catch block

Comment: @Sharath are you running this on a windows machine?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I tried hard coding it `print(tz.gettz('AMERICA/NEW_YORK'))` so it gives None

Comment: Can you try it with 'America/New_York'?
If that works, add `.title()` to `_tz.` (see updated answer).

Comment: you can install _dateutil_ by issuing `pip install python-dateutil` on Cygwin or Linux terminal